# how to truncate labels in apexcharts heatmap?

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I've long texts on x and y_axis . Is there a way to truncate (use ellipsis) for this.
I tried whith tspan( but its an Svg )

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `yaxis.labels.formatter` function

```
yaxis: {
  labels: {
    formatter: function(str) {
      const n = 10
      return str.length > n ? str.substr(0, n - 1) + '...' : str
    }
  }
}
```